# QED symbol with theorem counter as subscript

Tags: amsmath

I am using the amsthm package and the proof enviroment it provides. Occasionally I am writing proofs for theorems which include several claims with their respective proofs. I would like to redefine the qed symbol to be the usual tombstone symbol, having a subscript mentioning the number of the preceding claim/theorem.

I am not an advanced latex user so I am not sure how to refer to the theorem/claim counter, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE-Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this similar to what you'd like to get?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\let\cproof\proof
\def\endcproof{%
  \renewcommand\qedsymbol{\openbox\rlap{\textsubscript{\std@currentclaim}}}%
  \endproof
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[theorem]
\renewcommand{\theclaim}{\arabic{claim}}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\claim}{\std@patch@thm}{}{}
\newcommand{\std@patch@thm}{%
  \makeatletter
  \regexpatchcmd{\@thm}
    {(\c{refstepcounter}\cB.\cP.2\cE.)}
    {\1\c{std@savelabel}}
    {}{}%
  \makeatother
}
\newcommand{\std@savelabel}{\xdef\std@currentclaim{\@currentlabel}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Every duck can fly.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
We made a series of steps.

\begin{claim}
Ducks are nice.
\end{claim}

\begin{cproof}
Who can say differently?
\end{cproof}

\begin{claim}
Ducks rule.
\end{claim}

\begin{cproof}
See the \TeX.StackExchange chat.
\end{cproof}

The main statement follows.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

LaTeX has no notion of “last theorem”. So we have to hook in `\@thm` when it does `\refstepcounter`. This code limits the surgery to the `claim` environment.

[image]

A slightly different approach. I add a hook to `\@thm` just after `\refstepcounter{#2}`, so the `\@currentlabel` will be available.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,xpatch}

\makeatletter
% add a hook to \@thm
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}
  {\refstepcounter{#2}}
  {\refstepcounter{#2}\csname #2hook\endcsname}
  {}{}
\newcommand{\settheoremhook}[2]{%
  \@namedef{#1hook}{#2}%
}
\let\cproof\proof
\def\endcproof{%
  \renewcommand\qedsymbol{\openbox\rlap{\textsubscript{\currentclaim}}}%
  \endproof
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[theorem]
\renewcommand{\theclaim}{\arabic{claim}}

\makeatletter
\settheoremhook{claim}{\global\let\currentclaim\@currentlabel}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Every duck can fly.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
We made a series of steps.

\begin{claim}
Ducks are nice.
\end{claim}

\begin{cproof}
Who can say differently?
\end{cproof}

\begin{claim}
Ducks rule.
\end{claim}

\begin{cproof}
See the \TeX.StackExchange chat.
\end{cproof}

The main statement follows.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The hook executes `\csname #2hook\endcsname`, so it will do nothing unless the hook has been defined with `\settheoremhook`. Such hook can only be set for “main” theorems, so not for the children of other theorems (in the example, you cannot do `\settheoremhook{lemma}`, for instance).

The output is the same.

## With `hyperref`

If `hyperref` is loaded, the patch has to be delayed (and is different).

Here is code that works independently of `hyperref` being loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% add a hook to \@thm
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\@tempswatrue}{\@tempswafalse}
\if@tempswa
\catcode`#=12
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \xpatchcmd{\@thm}
      {\@currentHref}
      {\@currentHref\csname #2hook\endcsname}
      {}{}%
  }
\catcode`#=6
\else
  \xpatchcmd{\@thm}
    {\refstepcounter{#2}}
    {\refstepcounter{#2}\csname #2hook\endcsname}
    {}{}
\fi

\newcommand{\settheoremhook}[2]{%
  \@namedef{#1hook}{#2}%
}
\let\cproof\proof
\def\endcproof{%
  \renewcommand\qedsymbol{\openbox\rlap{\textsubscript{\currentclaim}}}%
  \endproof
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[theorem]
\renewcommand{\theclaim}{\arabic{claim}}

\makeatletter
\settheoremhook{claim}{\global\let\currentclaim\@currentlabel}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Every duck can fly.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
We made a series of steps.

\begin{claim}
Ducks are nice.
\end{claim}

\begin{cproof}
Who can say differently?
\end{cproof}

\begin{claim}
Ducks rule.
\end{claim}

\begin{cproof}
See the \TeX.StackExchange chat.
\end{cproof}

The main statement follows.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution does more or less what I needed.

Comment: @St.D. I have some ideas about how to improve the interface. Feel free to add comments.

Comment: One improvement I can think of is to have "Claim x" as a subscript instead of just the number x.

Comment: @St.D. Just change `\textsubscript{\currentclaim}` into `\textsubscript{Claim \currentclaim}`

Comment: For some reason, when I implement the commands in my main document, I get the error "! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\z@ \selectfont Claim \currentclaim". I am still looking at what is the problem, but do you have any idea what might be?

Comment: @St.D. Sorry, no: I'd need a full example showing the issue. Please open a new question with minimal code for debugging.

Comment: I found what causes the problem. It is the hyperref package. For some reason, even loading the package causes the error I mentioned above, which I don't know how to resolve. @egreg Do you think it is worth creating a new question about it?

Comment: @St.D. I added the code for the case `hyperref` is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of redefining the `\qed` command I would define a version with an optional parameter to be written as subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand\myqed[1][]{\qed\rlap{$_{\mathit{#1}}$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Let $a$ and $b$ be two odd integers. Then
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $ab$ is odd
  \item $a+ b$ is even
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  Let $a=2k+1$ and $b=2l+1$. Then $ab=(2k+1)(2l+1)=4kl+2k+2l+1=2(2kl+k+l)+1$ which proves the first part.
  \myqed[1]

  Similarly $a+b=2k+2l+2=2(k+l+1)$, which is even, and the second part is proven.
  \myqed[2]

  This completes the proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]